# Nginx passing url arguments as header

Tags: nginx, nginx-config

In the following example:

```
http {                                                                        
        server { # simple reverse-proxy                                       
        listen       8080;                                                    
            location / {                                                      
                set $token $arg_token;                                        
                #return 200 $token;                                           
                add_header test "test $token";                                
                proxy_pass http://localhost:5601;                             
            }                                                                 
        } ...
}
```

if I leave return 200 $token I obtain the token as response + in header (which is a normal behavior) but when I delete return I obtain only "test" as test header value, what am I missing please ?

Answer (score 1):

The `proxy_set_header` sets header that NGINX will use while communicating to the upstream/backend.

You *won't see* that added header in the response of NGINX back to the client.

If you want to see it, use `add_header` as well.

Comment: Thank you for your answer,  I've given the wrong example please check my edited question, thank you!

Comment: What is the HTTP status when you don't add `return`? If you app returns non-200 response, then `add_header` will not apply, unless you add `always` parameter to it.

Comment: What happens if you just use `add_header test "test $arg_token";` without `set`? Your issue might be an order of application for `set` + `add_header` + `proxy_pass`.

Comment: the problem is that the test is present it's just the $arg_token (or $token) that doesn't has value I don't understand why, I have test header = "test" without the token

Comment: ok that's really weird but it seems that the problem is from kibana, if I try another proxy_pass it works... :(

Comment: but it stills so weird that $arg_token won't be set in case of kibana...